# Private Airbrake source maps not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, airbrake

I'm attempting to set up private source maps using Airbrake following the documentation at airbrake.io/docs/features/private-sourcemaps.

From https://airbrake.io/docs/features/private-sourcemaps/#pattern-matching-option:

```
airbrake sourcemaps create --project-id PROJECT_ID \
    --from-file 'app.min.js.map'
    --name 'unique-name'
    --pattern '%app.min.js'
```

From this example, it seems the `name` parameter has to be a unique name. But when I scroll a little further down the page I see:

> For your private source map upload to function correctly it’s important you check that:
>
> - The `name` for the file https://example.com/app.min.js.map should be fully qualified.

Oh, so the name isn't just any random unique name, it has to be a FQN? If I'm uploading the source maps to Airbrake how do I know the URL to put here? The source maps won't be publicly available on my domain so if I put that URL there it will 404.

Looking at the [API docs](https://airbrake.io/docs/api/#create-source-map-v4) it seems `name` refers to yet another thing:

> `name` | The location of your minified version of `app.js` that should be publicly available

What should the name be then? Does `name` actually refer to different concepts if you're using the CLI vs the HTTP API?

I tried specifying name as both the path to the JS file (e.g. `/assets/js/some-hash.js`) as well as where the source map file should be if it were public (in both cases these values were unique).

I didn't get any errors when uploading via the API, but when I ran `airbrake sourcemaps list --project-id MY-PROJECT-ID` in the CLI I didn't see anything. That command only showed the source maps if I uploaded them with the CLI manually. But even in that case Airbrake didn't seem to find the source maps. Airbrake would show the following for `sourceMapErrors` under *Occurrences > Context*:

```
"https://exmaple.com/assets/js/some-hash.js": "http.Get url=\"https://exmaple.com/assets/js/some-hash.map\": got 404 Not Found, expected 200 OK"
```

Why is Airbrake attempting to look for it at that URL when it's not going to be publicly available? And why is it looking for a `.map` and not a `.js.map` file? Even when my source maps are made publicly available it doesn't work.

How am I suppose to get private source maps to work for Airbrake? I'm using the latest version of Airbrake for the browser: `@airbrake/browser@2.1.5`.